# Hidden subgroup problem

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, fourier-sampling, hidden-subgroup-problem

Let $H$ be a hidden subgroup of $G_1$ that is indistinguishable from subgroup $H^{\prime}$ by quantum Fourier sampling. Now take a larger group $G_2$ such that it contains $G_1$. Now if I do quantum Fourier sampling over $G_2$ instead of $G_1$ are they still indistinguishable?

Comment: Have you thought about specific $H$ and $H’$ or $G_1$ or $G_2$, in the context of, say, Shor’s algorithm?

Comment: @ Mark S I have a certain wreath product in mind but I intend to ask this in general framework. Partly because I 'think' this should be true in general and mainly because any such examples would be nice.

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange or mathoverflow *may* be welcoming to this question, but I would wait a couple of days before cross-posting (and also emphasize that you did ask it here without progress.)

Comment: @Mark S I tried to cross-post but couldn't.

Comment: Hi Root - I think you just ask the same question on one of the other forums, with a beginning comment to the effect of "I have asked this on Quantum Computing Stack Exchange a couple of weeks ago, without any answers... I'm asking here to see if there's any pointers..  Any help here would be appreciated!"